# Depth em alguns metodos do opencv

Tags: opencv, processamento-de-imagens

O que é o parametro `depth` que aparece em muitas funções do opencv? Por exemplo do `filter2D()`, o que eu entendi pelo que ta na documentação seria o numero de bits para representar a intensidade, está correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Depth

É o Data Type de cada elemento da imagem, ou seja, a exatidão de cada pixel. Quanto mais bits por pixel, melhor a representação de diferenças de cor e intensidades.

Por outro lado, isso pode dar mais complexidade ao criar uma segmentação por `Thresholding`, pois a variação de cores/intensidades é maior também.

Então a escolha do `depth` depende da aplicação desejada.

## Data Types

A [documentação oficial](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/intro.html#fixed-pixel-types-limited-use-of-templates) explica a razão de utilizar estes tipos de Data Types.

Na versão 4.0.0-beta:

- 8-bit unsigned integer (uchar)
- 8-bit signed integer (schar)
- 16-bit unsigned integer (ushort)
- 16-bit signed integer (short)
- 16-bit floating-point number (float)
- 32-bit signed integer (int)
- 32-bit floating-point number (float)
- 64-bit  floating-point number (double)

No [Github](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/traits.hpp) é possível encontrar os Data Types de `depth` no código a seguir:

```
/** @brief A helper class for cv::DataType
The class is specialized for each fundamental numerical data type supported by OpenCV. It provides
DataDepth<T>::value constant.
*/
template<typename _Tp> class DataDepth
{
public:
    enum
    {
        value = DataType<_Tp>::depth,
        fmt   = DataType<_Tp>::fmt
    };
};


#ifdef OPENCV_TRAITS_ENABLE_DEPRECATED

template<int _depth> class TypeDepth
{
#ifdef OPENCV_TRAITS_ENABLE_LEGACY_DEFAULTS
    enum { depth = CV_USRTYPE1 };
    typedef void value_type;
#endif
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_8U>
{
    enum { depth = CV_8U };
    typedef uchar value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_8S>
{
    enum { depth = CV_8S };
    typedef schar value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_16U>
{
    enum { depth = CV_16U };
    typedef ushort value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_16S>
{
    enum { depth = CV_16S };
    typedef short value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_32S>
{
    enum { depth = CV_32S };
    typedef int value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_32F>
{
    enum { depth = CV_32F };
    typedef float value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_64F>
{
    enum { depth = CV_64F };
    typedef double value_type;
};

template<> class TypeDepth<CV_16F>
{
    enum { depth = CV_16F };
    typedef float16_t value_type;
};

#endif

//! @}
```

Dependendo da versão do OpenCV são 7 Data Types, mais o Data Type legado `CV_USRTYPE1`

Ou são 8 Data Types a partir da versão 4.x, com a adição do novo [CV_16F](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/6d7f5871dbf9e1e9082c6a99f5358e413e844b80)

#### Python

No OpenCV 3.4.3 e Python 3.x alguns atributos podem ser obtidos com `[(i,type(getattr(cv2,i))) for i in dir(cv2)]`

E a lista dos data types de `depth`:

```
import cv2
import re


depths = [i for i in dir(cv2) if re.search('^CV_(?:\d+[A-Z]{1}|USRTYPE1)$', i, re.IGNORECASE)]
print(depths)
```

Que retorna: `['CV_16S', 'CV_16U', 'CV_32F', 'CV_32S', 'CV_64F', 'CV_8S', 'CV_8U']`

> Note que `depth` e `type` [são diferentes](http://answers.opencv.org/question/742/matrix-depth-equals-0/#747). Pois `type` é a combinação de `depth` + número de canais.

## ddepth

`ddepth` é o valor de `depth` da imagem destino, então este deve ser algum dos Data Types de `depth` ou -1, que significa o mesmo `depth` que a imagem fonte.