# Problema ao Executar Watershed Distance Transform no OpenCV 4.0.0

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencv, visão-computacional

Estou trabalho em um projeto de detecção de objetos. Utilizo OpenCV 4.0.0 e  codeblocks 16.01 no Ubuntu 18.04.1. Estou testando a técnica watershed distance transform usando o código deste tutorial:

https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/d2/dbd/tutorial_distance_transform.html

Apenas modifiquei o caminho para a minha imagem de teste, ficando assim:

```
// Load the image
    CommandLineParser parser( argc, argv, "{@input | ../../testes/img1.jpg | input image}" );
    Mat src = imread( parser.get<String>( "@input" ) );
    if( src.empty() )
    {
        cout << "Could not open or find the image!\n" << endl;
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <Input image>" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    else cout << "img ok\n";
```

O restante do código está exatamente igual ao do tutorial. Porém ao executá-lo, aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que possa estar acontecendo?

EDIT:
Fui testando etapa por etapa do algoritmo, eis que o erro acontece em:

```
// Perform the distance transform algorithm
Mat dist;
distanceTransform(bw, dist, DIST_L2, 3);
// Normalize the distance image for range = {0.0, 1.0}
// so we can visualize and threshold it
normalize(dist, dist, 0, 1.0, NORM_MINMAX);
imshow("Distance Transform Image", dist);
```

A imagem dist após executar a função distanceTranform() fica totalmente preta, sendo que o erro acontece em normalize().

Comment: Olá. Pela mensagem de erro, parece que o problema acontece na hora de exibir a imagem em uma janela gráfica (mais especificamente, na hora de setar a imagem no widget da janela). O seu código funciona com a imagem original do tutorial?

Comment: Acontece a mesma coisa. Após vários testes descobri onde está o erro (editei a pergunta), porém não sei como solucionar...

Comment: Você pode estar usando um tipo de imagem diferente do exemplo. A imagem do exemplo está em https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/cards.png , compare com sua imagem, qual a profundidade de ambas (gray, color, 8 bits, 16 bits)?

Answer (score 1):

Ao que parece, a função `imshow()` apenas mostras imagens no formato CV_8U. Então foi necessário alterar os parâmetros da função `normalize()`, ficando assim:

```
normalize(dist, dist, 0, 255.0, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8U);
```

No restante o algoritmo watershed funciona muito bem, porém é necessário tomar cuidado com esses detalhes: CV_8U, CV_32S, etc.

Comment: Para um pouco mais de informações sobre os data types, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/338350/75104). Em OpenCV é necessário estar atento a isso, pois a maioria das funções aceitam somente certo tipo de data type.